# creating an animated responsive popup pulling content from another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, responsive-design, popup

I am trying to create a responsive animated popup that pulls content from another page. This would be so that variable values can be passed from java-script (in parent page) to a PHP variable via URL query string (in popup content page).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#popup').css("display","hidden");
var href = "http://yoursite/anotherpage.php?var1=value1";
$.ajax({
   url:href,
   type:'GET',
   success: function(data){
       $('#content').html($(data).find('#popup').html());
       $('#popup').css("display","block");
   }
});
```